# Reading a PDF file using Java

Tags: pdf, pdf-reader

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [PDF to text tool or Java library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583615/pdf-to-text-tool-or-java-library)
>   [How read PDF using java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-read-pdf-using-java)

Is there any way i can read PDF files using JAVA. The pdf file contains images and text.. Its kind off irregular. I need to get the text alone. Any implementations???

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Google [`java pdf`](http://www.google.com/search?q=java+pdf) and you'll get a host of answers.

Comment: Here you have similar question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4784825/how-read-pdf-using-java

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [iText](http://www.itextpdf.com/). It is an open source library for reading, creating and modifying PDF files. I have recently used it and it works very well.